# What manufacturing process could be used for this part?

Tags: plastic

How might the "shell" in this picture be manufactured? What process could be used to achieve this geometry? It is made from plastic.

[image: render of component in question]

Comment: Can you provide more details? How big is this? What "plastic"?

Comment: Vacuum molding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might also have been made by thermoforming, in which a flat sheet of plastic is heated until it softens and then pressed against a replica of the finished part and allowed to cool and harden. If the process of conforming to the replica is aided by applying a vacuum in the space between the sheet and the replica, the process is called vacuum forming. this is popular for making large objects with thin walls especially if the finished part must be inexpensive.

Comment: Or hydroforming if metal is used, you can even do that yourself with a grease gun or a pressure washer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that given the size, it's probably a polyurethane [RIM moulding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_injection_molding). I have used [Midas Pattern](https://www.midaspattern.co.uk/) for such shells in the past. Here is an example from their website:

[image]